# R: looking for implementation of quantile regression with fixed effects by Machado and Silva (2019)

Tags: r, function, implementation, quantile-regression

I am looking for an R implementation of the quantile regression with fixed effects as proposed by Machado and Santos Silva (2019).

Is it included in any package or is anyone currently working on it?

I know that the authors implemented their approach in Stata (see `xtqreg`, https://jmcss.som.surrey.ac.uk/research.html). However, I cannot find an equivalent function for R.

Any help is welcome!

**Reference:** Machado, J.A.F. and Santos Silva, J.M.C. (2019), Quantiles via Moments, *Journal of Econometrics*, 213(1), pp. 145-173.